# Minecraft- spawner not spawning (1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm on a server using minimal plug-ins and found a zombie spawner. I've dug out a 9x3x9 space around the spawner, made sure the nearby caves are torched to prevent spawning, set the difficulty to normal, and made sure the light level around the spawner is 0. I do all this but the spawner still won't spawn anything.

I'm not sure what the problem could be and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try going over 256 blocks away from it and coming back (or alternatively at least 128 blocks above the surface). If it still doesn't work, you should list what type of server it is (Bukkit, Spigot, …) and what mods run on it. Also, do other spawners work?

Answer (score 3):

try to see if the server prevents mob spawners or mob spawning. Some servers Ive played on do this for lag reasons

Answer (score 2):

my best guess is that if there are mobs more than 6 mobs outside your mob spawner so i would check whether there are any mobs near by